# Can we adjust/change any thread's runtime?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads, kernel

Is it possible to adjust/change any thread's runtime just before deleting it? is there any libc api available or can we change it in kernel. The main thread creates few dynamic pthread. The time keeping is done using get-runtime() that read the runtime from syspage. The run time of cancel threads gets added to the main thread once the thread being canceled/deleted exits, which I am trying to avoid.

P.S: To change the behavior of pthreads to never cancel/delete is not an option.

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to change thread priority?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not very clear. Do you want do adjust the runtime itself or just the value of it that is kept? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi Jens, adjusting the value of it will work. Actually there is a threshold value for which a task can run.

Comment: Let's say pthread T1 is main thread and pthread T2 is one of 
the dynamically created threads.Consider the following sequence:
a:T1 calls runtime1 = get-runtime();
b:does something and probably T2 is also exiting during this time
c: T1 calls elapsed-time(runtime1 );

Comment: If the T2 is canceled/exits b/w step a and step c, we will cross the threshold as the runtime of T2 will get added to T1's runtime (as T2 has completed the exit). However if we take into account the asynchronous nature of pthread_cancel(), if the T2 exit completes after step c, we won't cross the threshold ( runtime of T2 is still not added to T1's runtime). Note that the runtime of thread getting deleted is added to main thread only at the time of thread's  
exit (the one getting deleted)

Comment: What is `get-runtime()`?

Comment: Also, you are free to add updates to your question. There is no need to squeeze them into comments.

Comment: Its a function which simply exports the runtime of a task that the kernel maintains. What I am trying as a workaround to adjust its runtime to 0 just before deleting it so that if its runtime also added to the main thread it will not cross the threshold.